# Too many re-renders even though I want an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to create a simple idle game so that I can dive deeper into web development.
However, react is complaining about too many re-render, but I do want to re-render every second.

This is the code I have at the moment.

```
> const Game = () => {   const [resourceCopper, setResourceCopper] =
> useState(0);
> 
>   const gatherCopper = () => {
>     setResourceCopper(resourceCopper + 1);   };
> 
>   setInterval(gatherCopper(), 1000);
> 
>   return (
>     <section className="main-window-container">
>       <section className="left-container">
>         <h3>Resources:</h3>
>         <p>Copper: {resourceCopper}</p>
>       </section>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate issue is that you're immediately executing `gatherCopper`, which immediately updates the state, rerender, and will cause an infinite loop.

You should remove the `()` behind gatherCopper in the `setInterval` call.

However, this code is very leaky, and because of the way React works you will create a new interval for every time the component renders. This will not work as expected.

The interval should be moved to a a [React hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) (i.e. `useEffect`), perhaps there's even hooks which wrap `setInterval`. A google search will probably come up with some good examples.

With React hooks you'll be able to start the interval when the component mounts for the first time, and you can also tell it to cancel the `setInterval` when the component unmounts. This is important to do.

**update**: Example with annotations ([sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-feynman-7o2jd?file=/src/App.js))

```
const Game = () => {
  const [resourceCopper, setResourceCopper] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // We move this function in here, because we only need this function once
    const gatherCopper = () => {
      // We use the 2nd way of calling setState, which is a function that will 
      // receive the current value. This is so that we don't have to use the resourceCopper
      // as a dependency for this effect (which would fire it more than once)
      setResourceCopper(current => current + 1);
    };

    // We tell the setInterval to call the new gatherCopper function
    const interval = setInterval(gatherCopper, 1000);

    // When an effect returns a function, it will be used when the component
    // is cleaned up (a.k.a. dismounts). We want to be neat and cancel up the interval
    // so we don't keep calling this on components that are no longer there
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [setResourceCopper]);

  return (
    <section className="main-window-container">
      <section className="left-container">
        <h3>Resources:</h3>
        <p>Copper: {resourceCopper}</p>
      </section>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the swift comment. I understand what you're trying to say. Would this be the way to do it? `useEffect(setInterval(gatherCopper, 1000), [resourceCopper]);`

Comment: resourceCopper should not be a dependency of this effect, because that way it will trigger the effect every time the value changes. You're also not cleaning up the interval. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you for the example. It was a bit more difficult than I had imagined it would be, but it works! Much appreciated!